# Deploy shiny app with Heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout)

Tags: r, heroku, shiny

I am trying to deploy my shiny app with heroku, but I have this output

```
web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-03-08T04:40:12.154157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-03-08T04:40:12.344233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-03-08T04:40:12.428222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-08T04:40:16.087134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sccosmo.herokuapp.com request_id=c07864e8-1e9e-49ea-ac9a-c6e87eafec83 fwd="187.232.16.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-08T04:40:16.167140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hello.herokuapp.com request_id=a3953768-7884-4654-8db1-dee6f6a92708 fwd="187.232.16.32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

How can I solve this?

This is my file run.app

```
library(shiny)

port <- Sys.getenv('PORT')

shiny::runApp(
  appDir = getwd(),
  host = '0.0.0.0',
  port = as.numeric(port)
)
```